# Running static C executable in AWS Lambda

Tags: c, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-linux

So I want to create a Lambda function that executes a raw C binary as part of the function. I am writing the function in Python with the help of boto3.

However I was wondering if this is just as simple as packaging the C executable in the deployment package and running the executable from Python, or if there is something more involved.

Right now I am worried that since the code may be compiled on a different OS, will Lambda be able to run it properly? Can I ensure that the Lambda is running on a certain platform and that way the packaged binary will be able to run?

Also if I do compile it on the right platform and the executable is ready to be run on whatever machine Lambda is using, is it just as simple as calling the binary in python or will the file structure be different when the code is run in Lambda and cause a problem finding the executable?

Thanks for any help! I'm pretty new to Lambda and AWS so its probably best to assume I don't know much.